# Why can't i drag and drop a class into a package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, javafx, package

Every time when I try to drag and drop a class into a package of a different project an error message pops up:- An unexpected exception occured. Please find the attached image to get info about the error log.

For example I want to drag and drop the Car.java into lab.unipi.core and the error appears as_: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxenW.png

Comment: I don't think drag and drop works. But have you tried copy the class and paste in the required package. Hope this works cause I've done it many times

Comment: Yep i just did it,thanks for that.Im new to eclipse
Can you post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: if there are no errors on your java class. It will go eventually. Please save it try executing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging and dropping doesn't work. You should copy and paste it.